# Extract data from user defined polygon and allow user to download as a layout and table/Excel file

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

A lot of components going into what I am trying to accomplish. I am making a web app where multiple data layers are displayed. I would like to create a geoprocessing tool that allows a user to input coordinates, and the tool ultimately creates a polygon where the polygon is used to extract the data underneath that polygon and be presented as a layout to download as well as an Excel file or something along the lines of.

Where I am at right now is creating a custom script tool to create a CSV file of the coordinates to use in ModelBuilder to begin the process. While I was able to get the code to work on an IDE, I am having issues transferring it to ArcGIS Pro and creating the parameters for the lat long points. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd  

point= [sys.argv[1]]
lat = [sys.argv[2]]
long = [sys.argv[3]]
 
dict = {'point': point, 'lat': lat, 'long': long}  
       
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

output= sys.argv[4]
    
df.to_csv(output)
```

I would like the user to be able to put in as many coordinates as sometimes it will be more than four coordinates. But what I am getting now in the Excel file is:

[image: excel file]

I would like them to list down the column rather than all in one field so that I can use point to line, then line to polygon to create the polygon.

As you can tell this is a little chaotic in my head and might not even work as I plan.

Do you have any advice for getting this to work?

Comment: Looks like the delimiter is ';'. You probably want to set that to a comma, this way when the cvs is opened it will have the layout that you want.

Comment: While you mention ArcGIS Pro and ModelBuilder, and have tagged your question with ArcPy, the code that you have presented does not include that or any other spatial library.